# Compiling a C program with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

A simple question that I cannot seem to find. When I am compiling a program with gcc my professor tells me to have -g and -o when I am compiling it and I am not too sure why. I could not find it in the man pages of gcc with there being so much on there.

For example...

```
gcc -g -o myprogram myprogram.c
```

Comment: The docs are pretty easy to find. :-(  Here's a bunch of them: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/.  Picking a specific version, you can dig in to the options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary.

Comment: I know that the docs are easy to find but when I'm searching specifically for -o and -g there are over 80 results to click through and I couldn't seem to find.

Comment: Or you can use the option summary to find the one you're looking for and navigate from there.  It's not how I'd like to see the documentation, but it is usable. :-)  BTW, I recommend compiling with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` as well.  Otherwise the compiler will fail to warn you about a lot of issues.

Comment: Going to use the manual to look those two up haha but thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-g` means to include debugging information, which enables a debugger to know where a named object (variable) is in the memory or registers of the executing process and to know which instructions correspond to which lines of source code.

`-o myprogram` says to put the output file in `myprogram`. (If you do not specify `-o` with a file name, GCC defaults to putting the output in a file named `a.out`.)